# iPhone mail: table doesn't stretch to 100% because of an anchor tag?

Tags: html, css, iphone, email, html-table

I'm designing an html newsletter which runs so far very correct on every email client.

On mobile devices it should stretch to 100% width, which it does so far.

**But:**

On iphone mail when the mail opens, for a second I see the hundred percent width until then a space on the right gets added. It's always the same spaced space.

I tried reducing my code to the minimum to see what the reason could be. There I found out it could be links, it could be a border. Sometimes it works again and then again not.

Is there some mystery about 100% width on iphone in html newsletters that I didn't yet know about?

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

        <title>Newsletter</title>

        <style type="text/css">


            /* Client-specific Styles */
            #outlook a{padding:0;} /* Force Outlook to provide a "view in browser" button. */
            body{width:100% !important;} .ReadMsgBody{width:100%;} .ExternalClass{width:100%;} /* Force Hotmail to display emails at full width */
            body{-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;} /* Prevent Webkit platforms from changing default text sizes. */

            /* Reset Styles */
            body{margin:0; padding:0;}
            img{border:0; height:auto; line-height:100%; outline:none; text-decoration:none;}
            table td{border-collapse:collapse; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
            #backgroundTable{height:100% !important; margin:0; padding:0; width:100% !important;}


            body { 
                background-color: #EEEDEC; 
                font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 15px;
                line-height: 1.5em;
                font-weight: 100;
                text-align: left;
                width: 100%;
            }


            p {
                margin-bottom: 20px;
            }

            a {
                color: #C5111A;
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            table {
                width: 100%;
                text-align: left;
            }

            img { max-width: 100%; }

            table.outter {
                width: 100%;
                background-color: #fff;
            }

            table.center {
                width: 100%;
                background-color: #fff;
            }

            h2 {
                font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 15px;
                font-weight: 100;
                margin-bottom: 20px;
                height: 30px;
                line-height: 30px;
                color: #fff;
                padding-left: 10px;
                background-color: #C5111A;

                background: #C5111A;
                background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#c4171d), to(#d6404c));
                background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c4171d, #d6404c);
                background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #c4171d, #d6404c);
                background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #c4171d, #d6404c);
                background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #c4171d, #d6404c);

                filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#c4171d,endColorstr=#d6404c); 
                zoom: 1;

                -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
                -moz-border-radius: 3px;
                border-radius: 3px;

            }



        </style>

    </head>

    <body leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" offset="0">
        <center>

            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="main">

             <tr>
               <td align="center" valign="top">
                <!-- outter -->
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="outter">


                <tbody>

                    <!-- BEGINN -->


                    <!-- BOX -->
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top">
                            <!-- center -->
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="center">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td valign="top" >

                                            <!-- box -->
                                            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td valign="top">

                                                            <h2 class="h2">Heading</h2>




                                                           <p>This is a Paragraph</p>
                                                           <a href="http://www.google.de">This is a link</a>

                                                        </td>


                                                    </tr>

                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                            <!-- /box -->

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>   
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <!-- /center -->
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <!-- END -->

                </tbody>
            </table>

</td></tr>
         </table>

        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

In this provided code 100% width will only work without the anchor.

Comment: Some code or rendered result will be helpful for others to help you.

Comment: There are extra </td></tr> before your </center>.

Comment: Updated, still the same problem.

Comment: This really freaks me out. I mean how could an anchor affect the 100% width of the table?

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by anchor, but considering removing <center> tag since it's no longer valid in html5. Use css instead.

Comment: By anchor I just mean a link and this really confused me. Since the last 6 hours I couldn't find out why this is happening.

Comment: I have the same problem but it doesn't seem to be anything to do with the `<a />`. I have been testing all morning trying and can't seem to get a nested center align tables to work with 100% width

Comment: @John Magnolia This is somehow good to hear that someone else also experienced this problem. Would be very cool to hear a solution to this if you stumble across it!

Comment: In the end I gave up and gave it a fixed width 480px. The iphone just doesn't seem to like 100% width if there is no padding.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
<body style="min-width: 100%">
```

fixes the problem.

Comment: Have to confirm this, too. I just had the same problem again and fixed it with your answer now. Perfect!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found a working solution:

Just set:

```
table {
    width: 99%; /* 99.99 % doesn't seem to work */
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

To get rid of the very small minimal gap, I just set the background-color the same as my table.

Fixed for now!

Answer (score 1):

Just posted this solution to a related issue: [Link in 100% width table results in 90% width table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398227/link-in-100-width-table-results-in-90-width-table/10711039#10711039)

This MacRumors thread provides a solution to the issue: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1158457

> Try to put align="center" and style="text-align:center" onto the first table and then put style="text-align:left" onto the second one if necessary.

If you wrap your content in a parent table with center alignment, this oddly seems to eliminate the right margin on the iPhone mail reader.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and reactivate my interested in this. I totally ignored it but now came up with an easy fix. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

a {display:block;} seems to help. i am not really sure, but on the first try, i wrapped that anchor in a paragraph and modified a as said.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I've tried this before but it didn't work eather. I am still stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

Using `min-width` and `margin:0 auto;` fixed completely this issue for me.