# Link in 100% width table results in 90% width table

Tags: iphone, ios, email, html-email

This is REALLY wierd.

This below code should result in a 100% width e-mail, with a lime colored top. But because the TD contains a link, the whole table is now 90% (or so) - but only in iPhone e-mail. Remove the link and the email is correct... What's going on?

https://s3.amazonaws.com/resultcaptures/C1C356D4-EAC0-4A50-B278-04155E256E51.png

**I've boiled my email down to this:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Email</title>    
</head>
<body bgcolor="brown" style="margin:0;padding:0; ">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" bgcolor="black">
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="Lime">
                <div><a href="#" alt="">This</a> is a link</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Nothing is wrong with it... right? ...or am I blind?

Comment: would be great to find an answer. same problem here with no results yet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493272/iphone-mail-table-doesnt-stretch-to-100-because-of-an-anchor-tag

Comment: Finally found a working fix. Posted also at my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493272/iphone-mail-table-doesnt-stretch-to-100-because-of-an-anchor-tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This MacRumors thread provides a solution to the issue: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1158457

> Try to put align="center" and style="text-align:center" onto the first table and then put style="text-align:left" onto the second one if necessary.

If you wrap your content in a parent table with center alignment, this oddly seems to eliminate the right margin on the iPhone mail reader.

Answer (score 0):

There is for sure a problem with iOS. The problem is that the e-mail gets scaled down to fit the width of the e-mail client, but when the mail is narrower than the e-mail client this accours - but only with e-mails with anchors in.

Set the with of the table to 320px to get rid of it, but say goodbye to elastic layout.

Comment: You can't use elastic layouts in html email unfortunately (You can vertically) which severely constricts what can be done with emails

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a working solution:

Just set:

```
table {
    width: 99%; /* 99.99% doesn't seem to work */
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

To get rid of the very small minimal gap, just set the background-color the same as your table.

Fixed for now!

I had the same issue: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493272/iphone-mail-table-doesnt-stretch-to-100-because-of-an-anchor-tag)